# Can i use class list and remove it after animation is done at the same time

Tags: javascript

is it possible to add a class to an html element and right away remove the class after the class style is added using javascript .. please help

Comment: yes you can do that but the style is related to the class so when you remove it the style is gone

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: is the class an animation you want removed after it completes 1 iteration?

Comment: Please expand your question and provide more clarification.

Comment: @AlexZeDim i made a hamburger menu and below that i have a div containing the list items and by the help of CSS and javaScript i toggled the hamburger menu to move the div left : -30vh and again toggle it back to left : 0vh . i also wanted that if the div is at 0vh and even if i click any where in the screen i want it to toggle back to -30vh , how can i do that

Comment: @SaymoinSam i made a hamburger menu and below that i have a div containing the list items and by the help of CSS and javaScript i toggled the hamburger menu to move the div left : -30vh and again toggle it back to left : 0vh . i also wanted that if the div is at 0vh and even if i click any where in the screen i want it to toggle back to -30vh , how can i do that

Comment: @AlexZeDim i made a hamburger menu and below that i have a div containing the list items and by the help of CSS and javaScript i toggled the hamburger menu to move the div left : -30vh and again toggle it back to left : 0vh . i also wanted that if the div is at 0vh and even if i click any where in the screen i want it to toggle back to -30vh , how can i do that ... PLEASE HELP ME PLEASE

Comment: well can you post your code so we can help you

Comment: @SaymoinSam okay

Comment: @SaymoinSam HERE IS THE HTML

Comment: HEY WHERE DO I ADD THE CODE ITS SAYING TOO LONG

Comment: If it's too long then you can make a repo at `github` and publish the link to it, although the required is to post only the minimal code to produce the problem and that should be acceptable in SO snippets

Comment: thankyou @SaymoinSam